# MassTransit RabbitMQ throws intermittent AlreadyClosedException (Connection Disposed)

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am receiving the following intermittent exception from MassTransit (5.5.5) when trying to publish to RabbitMQ.

```
Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, 
initiated by Application, code=200, text="Connection Disposed",
classId=0, methodId=0, cause=, RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException
```

I am using Autofac to register the services. Im struggling to see where the connection could be getting disposed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Autofac registration**

```
      builder.AddMassTransit(c =>
            {   
        c.AddConsumer<VoucherIssuedConsumer>();

                c.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                {
                    var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("..."), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("...");
                        h.Password("...");                        
                    });

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "vouchers", e =>
                    {
                        e.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(21)));
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<VoucherIssuedConsumer>(context);
                    });       

                }));
            });
```

**Publishing**

```
 internal class VoucherIssuedListener 
  {        
        private readonly IBus publisher;

        public VoucherIssuedListener(IBus publisher)
        {           
            this.publisher = publisher;
        }         

        public async Task HandleAsync()
        {
            var message = ...

            await publisher.Publish(message);  // Throwing here intermittently
        }    
  }
```

Comment: How are you initializing the IBus interface for the publisher ?

Comment: Where's your bus getting started?

Comment: Your listener class should depend upon `IPublishEndpoint`, not `IBus` – it's the same instance, but semantics of requesting the smallest interface.